# Update: Eclipse and one drive

Tags: eclipse, onedrive

I have a desktop and a laptop which i bring to uni. Is there a way to put eclipse workspace on  One Drive (sky drive) and then be able to work on it from multiple computers? I have tried it but it seems to mess up the folders. I.e. the package folder is now a standard folder.

UPDATE:

I found this link but I'm not too sure it will work. Anyone willing to explain if this will work?

Here's the link: http://www.howtogeek.com/174765/how-to-sync-any-folder-with-skydrive-on-windows-8.1/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the workspace there, you need to make sure that the project files such as `.project` and `.classpath`, which are automatically generated by Eclipse, are also stored. Otherwise, Eclipse won't recognize the folders as project directories.

Still even if you store all files you can encounter problems in some cases if you're using different versions of Eclipse across different computers, and with different plugins, features and so on. A simple solution is to also store the Eclipse installation itself so that you use the same Eclipse across all computers.

Comment: ok well when i get more time i will definitely try that out. I think it should work because you can run eclipse of a usb stick. Will let you guys know later this year.

Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

OneDrive does not (yet!) support syncing files that start with periods, like the .eclipse settings folders.  Because of this you will not see those items sync over OneDrive.

Comment: do you know of another solution. I really want to do it over the cloud without having to keep importing the workspace and update it.

Answer (score 0):

Make **NEW FOLDER** in onedrive. Then run Eclipse with this folder. Run Eclipse with this folder in another computer.